# Cannot connect to MongoDB router in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I followed [this guide](https://dzone.com/articles/composing-a-sharded-mongodb-on-docker) on how to setup a sharded MongoDB cluster with Docker containers.

It all seemed to work as it should because there were no error messages in the logs and the `sh.status()` command also gives the correct output:

```
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("61e566e526f7ddf44513d655")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "mongors1",  "host" : "mongors1/mongors1n1:27017,mongors1n2:27017,mongors1n3:27017",  "state" : 1,  "topologyTime" : Timestamp(1642424080, 1) }
  active mongoses:
        "5.0.2" : 2
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled: yes
        Currently running: no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts: 0
        Migration results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1        1024
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
        {  "_id" : "testDb",  "primary" : "mongors1",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("31fab861-18eb-453b-9cdf-bdac1723be0c"),  "timestamp" : Timestamp(1642424142, 1),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                testDb.testCollection
                        shard key: { "shardingField" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongors1        1
                        { "shardingField" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "shardingField" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : mongors1 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

The routers are listening on port `27019` and `27020` but when i try to access the cluster with the Compass app I just get a timeout.

I used this connection string:
`mongodb://localhost:27020,localhost:27019`

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. I don't know why but adding `--bind_ip 0.0.0.0` to each mongos   process worked:

```
mongos1:
    container_name: mongos1
    image: mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongocfg1
      - mongocfg2
    command: mongos --configdb mongors1conf/mongocfg1:27017,mongocfg2:27017,mongocfg3:27017 --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    expose:
      - "27017"
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Because default setting is listening only localhost address

Comment: The bind_ip is the important part here. Thanks.